# Zookeeper service fails to start with systemd using "Type=forking" but runs manually

Tags: google-cloud-platform, debian, apache-zookeeper

I have a Zookeeper service that I am trying to manage with systemd. The service definition is as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=Zookeeper Daemon
Documentation=http://zookeeper.apache.org
Requires=network.target
After=network.target

[Service]    
Type=forking
WorkingDirectory=/opt/zookeeper
User=zookeeper
Group=zookeeper
ExecStart=/opt/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh start /opt/zookeeper    /conf/zoo.cfg
ExecStop=/opt/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh stop /opt/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg
ExecReload=/opt/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh restart /opt/zookeeper    /conf/zoo.cfg
TimeoutSec=30
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

When I try to start the service using systemctl, I get the following error:

`zookeeper.service: Main process exited, code=exited,                      status=3/NOTIMPLEMENTED zookeeper.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.`

However, when I run the zkServer.sh script manually, Zookeeper starts without any issues:
/opt/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh start /opt/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg

I suspect the issue might be related to the Type=forking directive in the systemd service file, but I'm not sure how to address it.

Has anyone encountered this issue before or have suggestions on how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was permission the following resolved the issue

sudo chown zk:zk /data/zookeeper
sudo chown -R zk:zk /data/zookeeper/version-2

sudo chown zk:zk /opt/zookeeper/logs/

sudo chown zk:zk /opt/zookeeper